# Can not setcwd to relative home directory (perl) Net::SFTP::Foreign

Tags: perl, bash, scripting, ftp, sftp

I am trying to access remote server via SFTP. I am using Net::SFTP::Foreign for this. Problem arises when I try to change directory to to user's home directory. It is not allowing to change directory as in shell.

```
cd ~
cd ~/folder
```

My perl code is as follows.

```
 $sftp->setcwd("~/aast-backup/$backup_type") or die "unable to change cwd: " . $sftp->error;
```

## Error shown

```
unable to change cwd: Couldn't get realpath for remote '/home/ftpkasi/aast-backup/~/aast-backup/differential
```

Please show some light into this. Thanks in advance...

Answer (score 2):

The answer is in the [documentation](http://search.cpan.org/~salva/Net-SFTP-Foreign-1.75/lib/Net/SFTP/Foreign.pm) for the `cwd` method:

> $sftp->cwd
>
> Returns the remote current working directory.
>
> **When a relative remote path is passed to any of the methods on this package, this directory is used to compose the absolute path.**

So the relative path you're passing to `setcwd` is being appended to your initial `cwd`. You can see this in the error message you get. The initial `cwd` is

```
/home/ftpkasi/aast-backup/
```

and when you call

```
$sftp->setcwd("~/aast-backup/$backup_type")
```

it tries to change to the directory

```
/home/ftpkasi/aast-backup/~/aast-backup/differential
```

which obviously doesn't exist.